# Swift Issue with a Delegate among Two methods

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have a strange issue with same delegate(s) in among some methods in ViewController.swift. For example:

We have ViewController class with ToDoItemsDelegate such as this:

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ToDoItemsDelegate {

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         let todoitemsDelegate = ToDoItems(delegate: self)

         print("Part 1: How many to do items?: \(todoitemsDelegate.items.count)")

         secondPart()
     } 

     func secondPart() {

         let todoitemsDelegate = ToDoItems(delegate: self)

         print("Part 2: How many to do items?: \(todoitemsDelegate.items.count)")
     }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Part 1: How many to do items?:   5
Part 2: How many to do items?:   0
```

I don't understand why the secondPart() method doesn't give the right number like the first method "First Part: 5". No clue... It supposed to be work if you have a delegate to work among methods in ViewController. I tried to create a extra delegate and it behaved the same thing. Any idea what is wrong with it? Any suggestion appreciated. Thanks!

**Edited (I added more details)**

**ToDoItems.swift**

```
protocol ToDoItemsDelegate {

}

struct Item {

     var title: String!
     var description: Int!

}

class ToDoItems {

     let delegate: ToDoItemsDelegate

     init(delegate: ToDoItemsDelegate) {
          self.delegate = delegate
     }

     var items = [Item]()

}
```

Comment: Your print statement in `secondPart` isn't referring to the instance you create in that function, it doesn't seem like your current code should even compile.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish with the delegates.

Comment: @picciano don't understand why I have `secondPart` method with only 0 items not 5 items like the `first method`

Comment: In secondPart() you are referencing `todoitemsDelegate`, but it appear to be a local variable inside the viewDiLoad function and should not be accessible here.

Comment: @picciano Ok. what is the best way to get it work? Any example?

Comment: That the confusing part, not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: @picciano I added more details. You can see extra codes.

Comment: Your code as it is in the question would not give the output you are saying it does.  It would print 0 in both places.

Comment: @dan, that's exactly what my answer below would get (just edited) too

Comment: @dan I didn't add more code above. I am sure it will give you hint that I have code in my methods in ToDoItems class. It has addedItems into Array. I tested it on ToDoItems class to see if I have items and I have 5 items already. So this code is good so far. But I still don't understand why in ViewController.swift has one is 5 (in viewDidLoad) and other is 0 (secondMethod). Make sense?

Comment: How are we supposed to help you solve your problem if the code you posted doesn't even demonstrate the problem?  Create a [mcve] if you want anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: @dan WMios gave the right solution to resolve my issue. It printed 5 on both times not 0. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the following. `todoitemsDelegate` is being declared outside of the functions and then assigned in `viewDidLoad` before it gets used. Now it will print the same value both times (0, as expected):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ToDoItemsDelegate {

     var todoitemsDelegate : ToDoItems? 

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         todoitemsDelegate = ToDoItems(delegate: self)

         print("Part 1: How many to do items?: \(todoitemsDelegate!.items.count)")

         secondPart()
     } 

     func secondPart() {

         print("Part 2: How many to do items?: \(todoitemsDelegate!.items.count)")
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't give the right because of error. When I moved it outside of the functions. Here it is what I got an error: `Arguement type 'NSObject -> () -> ViewController does not conform to expected to type ToDoItemsDelegate'` Any idea what is wrong with it?

Comment: It'd help if I knew what your delegate was. Your question is unclear.

Comment: I have `ToDoItems` class with Struct and other func methods. If I don't use delegate for to pass value between ToDoItems class and UIViewController. I got no data whatever. So I added Protocol in ToDoItems so that I can take data from there to pass to UIViewController. It worked only in `viewDidLoad()` method but not on `secondPart()` method.

Comment: Post code. You're being too vague.

Comment: Ok. Let me share it.

Comment: @HotDudeSmith, see my edit. Changed the line with the error to `let todoitemsDelegate = ToDoItems(delegate: self as! ToDoItemsDelegate)`

Comment: I shared some the code. See above (my question). I tried to run what you provided the latest code and still receive the error.

Comment: You can't refer to `self` like that in a property declaration

Comment: @dan I added some codes in my question. Any idea what is wrong with it?

Comment: @HotDudeSmith, fixed it. Look now. Should print zero both times.

Comment: It worked. Now it prints 5 both times. Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: Great! Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two different ToDoItems. `ToDoItems != self`

Every time you allocate a new ToDoItems you are initializing the new item's properties. i.e. `var items = [Item]()`

**todoitemsDelegate** in viewDidLoad and **todoitemsDelegate** secondPart are different objects and have two different items variables.